# How to search using wildcard in VIM

Tags: search, vim, wildcard

Using the standard search function (/) in VIM, is there a way to search using a wildcard (match 0 or more characters)?

Example:

I have an array and I want to find anywhere the array's indices are assigned.

```
array[0] = 1;
array[i] = 1;
array[index]=1;
```

etc.

I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
/array*=
```

if it's possible.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the wildcard works. It does not match 0 or more characters, it matches 0 or more *of the preceding atom*, which in this case is `y`. So searching

```
/array*=
```

will match any of these:

```
arra=
array=
arrayyyyyyyy=
```

If you want to match 0 or more of any character, use the 'dot' atom, which will match any character other than a newline.

```
/array.*=
```

If you want something more robust, I would recommend:

```
/array\s*\[[^\]]\+\]\s*=
```

which is "array" followed by 0 or more whitespace, followed by anything contained in brackets, followed by 0 or more whitespace, followed by an "equals" sign.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
array.*
```

.* makes it mean something or nothing.in array* , * goes to y .